# how to send data with edit or delete ajax request in datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

There are many questions and answers related to send data with ajax request in datatable jquery. But I didn't find how to send data when default datatable delete button clicked in ajax request

I know this is confusing so I show you some code and images

```
 $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
  $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
   url:'action2.php',
   dataType:'json',
   columns:{
    identifier : [1, 'sub_category_id'],
    editable:[[5, 'GST'], [6, 'price'],
    [8, 'Commission'], [10, 'discount']]
   },
   restoreButton:false,
   onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
   {
    if(data.action == 'delete')
    {
     $('#' + data.id).remove();
     $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }
   }
  });
 });
```

see this is default code of datatable jquery for edit or deleting data.

now I also show you initialized datatable jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
      "processing" : true,
      "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-2'<'#selecttype'>><'col-sm-3'<'#activelist'>><'col-sm-4'f>>" +
             "<'row'<'col-sm-12't>>" +
             "<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
      "serverSide" : true,
  "order" : [[1,"asc"]],
  "ajax" : {
    url:"action2.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: {                 <<-------------=
      fetch: "fetch",
      "status" : function(){
        try{
          console.log("trying ... ");
          return document.querySelector("#activelistbox").value;
        }catch(e){
          console.log("message "+e);
          return "Active List";
        }
      },
      "type" : function(){
        try{
          console.log("trying ... ");
          return document.querySelector("#selectbox").value;
        }catch(e){
          console.log("message "+e);
          return "All";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
};
```

see here I use data parameter to send data.

now I show you table image

[This is table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIl4o.png)

This is payload data
[payload data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLqh9.png)

Now please tell me how can i send data

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation for the [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option. Specifically, look at (a) the notes relating to `serverSide: true`, since you are using that; and (b) the form of the option which uses a function: `"data": function ( d ) { ... }`. There are questions already on this site covering these items, if you do some more research. But the official documentation should also help. You need to use the functional syntax for `data`, as that is how you can send different (dynamic) data with each new request.

Comment: Checkout this github project where row edit functionality is implemented. Whenever you edit a row and save, an ajax call is made to api. https://github.com/sinhashubh/datatable-examples